# Error en sqlite

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

Estoy trabajando en android studio con base de datos `sqlite` y me genera el siguiente error a la hora de eliminar todos los datos de una tabla:

Al usar este código:

```
db.delete("tabla",null,null);
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "*": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE *FROM tabla

Comment: Coloca un espacio para separar el asterisco en la consulta: edita la consulta así: `DELETE * FROM tabla`.

Answer (score 1):

No creo que la línea que describes sea el problema ya que funcionaria sin problema usando el método [delete()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])):

`db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);`

En otra parte de tu código debes estar usando el método [execSQL()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)), en el cual defines un string con la consulta:

```
 db.execSQL("DELETE *FROM tabla");
```

y no tienes un espacio definido antes de `FROM`, debes corregir.

```
 db.execSQL("DELETE * FROM tabla");
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta pegado el **asterisco** a la palabra **FROM**.
Tu consulta debe ser `DELETE * FROM tabla;`.